# UIScrollView not scrolling (Auto Layout enabled and xibs)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, xib

I have been stuck on this problem for days and could use any help! This is my view heirarchy:[image: View Hierarchy]

and I have no auto Layout errors. I have an outlet for both the scrollview and the contentview in my viewcontroller file and, after following many tutorials, have added this to my viewController file:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.scrollView layoutIfNeeded];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.bounds.size;
}
```

Everything shows up in the simulator as I expect it to be with no autolayout errors in the console, but nothing scrolls. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What is the content size and what is the scroll view size ?

Comment: the content size is 800 (vertically scrolling) and scrollview size is the whole size of the frame

Comment: Did you check this size in `viewDidLoad` ? If yes, you should check it in view did appear, because in `viewDidLoad` the frame is not fully updated.

Comment: Sorry, i thought you meant expected :P. ` -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"Content width and height is %f and %f", self.contentView.bounds.size.width,self.contentView.bounds.size.height );
     NSLog(@"Scroll width and height is %f and %f", self.scrollView.bounds.size.width,self.scrollView.bounds.size.height );
}` prints `Content width and height is 600.000000 and 601.000000
Scroll width and height is 600.000000 and 600.000000`

Comment: So from what I've seen in your comment, content size is `600,601` and scroll view size is `600,600` so there's your problem. Content size is almost equal with the scroll size (1 px) difference. That's why you can't scroll. You must have a content size bigger than the scroll view size

Comment: Is it something im doing wrong in IB? Because there I have it statically set to those numbers but its using auto layout so shouldnt the width change depending on the size of the view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99018/discussion-between-danypata-and-mark-bourke).

Comment: Make your content size bigger than scrollview size.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. There was a problem with my view hierarchy constraints. These are the correct constraints. Thanks to @danypata for solving this

[image: View Contstraints]